# How can i get the value on the same name param/key on the url format with flask?

Tags: python, flask, get

**url that I send to flask webservice :**
http://localhost:5000/bendauji?do_nomor=DOCKET/ICN/05-2017/5538&[{"nourutbenda": "0 "}, {"nourutbenda": "3 "}]

**flask error respond :**
code 400, message Bad request syntax ('GET /bendauji?do_nomor=DOCKET/ICN/05-2017/5538&[{"nourutbenda": "0 "}, {"nourutbenda": "3 "}] HTTP/1.1')

**code below in flask :**

do_nomor = request.args.get('do_nomor')

nourutbenda = reguest.args ???????

I need value do_nomor and list of nourutbenda. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

If you sending your value in this format

```
http://localhost:8000/bendauji?nourutbenda=2&nourutbenda=5
```

then you can use getlist to get the `nourutbenda`

```
request.args.getlist('nourutbenda')
```